# Issue with dynamically loaded questions in the "Newest" tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, question-lists

Below a self explanatory screenshot of the issue

> [image]

As you can see, when I click on the "x question with new activity" I get results similiar to the "Active" tab.

Another screenshot

> [image]

I am pretty sure this is something new because I was always getting "asked ..." and never the "answered .." or "modified .." when I am on the Newest tab.

To reproduce the issue, simply keep the notification *growing* (Don't click on it for a good moment). Then click on it and if there is any new question with an edit or an answer, you will notice the issue. The last activity will be picked instead

Comment: I haven't observed this behavior while checking for it off an on today (after clicking a "Watched Tag" then "Newest").  Is it recurring?  Is there any particular way you get to this tab/view that causes it?  Maybe browser specific (I'm using Firefox)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Don't click the new activity element immediately - leave it for 10 or 20 minutes, then click it. By that time, it's likely that one or more of the questions will have been answered or modified

Comment: @CertainPerformance Ah, I see... if one of the "new activity" questions has an update, then it will show that activity time instead of the "asked" time.  Looks like this is an attempt to update the vote/answers and gets too much info.

Comment: I'll add that the issue this "fix" is trying to address is easily compensated for - just click the "Newest" button again will reload all the tab data (and refresh the questions that were there, which this adjustment does not do).

Comment: Might be obvious but I'd still mention it - the same happens if you have a custom filter that is set to sort by newest. In that case you're [*not* at the "Newest" tab](https://i.imgur.com/ckFett4.png) yet do use the same behaviour.

Comment: Possibly relata on meta stack exchange: [“X questions with new activity” showing incorrect information in windows with multiple tag filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343767/344280) and [“X questions with new activity” notification now triggering for ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343756/344280).

Comment: FYI: It's still happening. I noticed the same behaviour again just now.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, I see this all the day

Comment: @TemaniAfif You have to wonder why it's still happening, eh? Heh. Oh well... no biggie really. It just looks odd whenever I/we see a post that looks like it was asked by a high rep member. Instead, it was modified in some way.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner well, now I refresh the page instead of clicking on the notifications ;) like this I am sure I only get "Asked by ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

The problem was simply that when we loaded the new questions, we weren't telling the renderer that we were on a "newest" list, so it was defaulting to showing the latest activity.  Everything else would have been correct.  The page was only been notified about new questions and the order they were added in was newest to oldest.

I didn't dig to see how old this issue is, but I'm guessing it's been around since we added realtime loading.  To be noticed, a page would have to get the new question notification and sit around long enough for someone to do something on the question.